MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch: Operand type is not supported for $vectorSearch: objectId
I'm using a langchain script in order to make a similarity search of a query embedding in an embedding's MongoDb collection but I want to pre filter the documents to search only in the documents that are $in an objectId array.
// Get the list of embeddings _ids to preFilter
const documentData =  await documentCollection.findOne(
  { "_id": documentId },
  { "embededings": 1 }
)
const documentEmbeddingsId = documentData.embeddings

// Embed query
const query = "What is this document about?"
const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
  modelName:"XXX",
  openAIApiKey: "XXX"
})
const embeddedQuery = await embeddings.embedQuery(query)

// Similarity search
const vectorStore = new MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch(embeddings, {
  collection,
  indexName: "XXX",
  textKey: "XXX", 
  embeddingKey: "XXX", 
});
const preFilter = {
    preFilter: {
      _id: {
        $in: documentEmbeddingsId
      },
    },
}
const storingResponse = await vectorStore.similaritySearchVectorWithScore(embeddedQuery,4,preFilter)

Running this code returns this error:
'Error: MongoServerError: Operand type is not supported for $vectorSearch: objectId'.
Is the error in the preFilter? Or is this type of filter not supported by mongodb? Any ideas on how I can make this search?

The documentEmbeddingsId is an ObjectId array. When I try to pass it as a string array I get this error:
Error: MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Path '_id' needs to be indexed as token
